# Node app crashing again and again due to mongo query

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my db collection document.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55e86e98f493590878bb45d7"),
"RecordID" : 84096380,
"FN" : "Michael",
"MI" : "",
"LN" : "Horn",
"NAME_PRE" : "MR",
"ADDR" : "160 Yankee Camp Rd",
"CITY" : "Telford",
"ST" : "TN",
"ZIP" : 37690,
"APT" : "",
"Z4" : 2200,
"DPC" : 605,
"CAR_RTE" : "R001",
"WALK_SEQ" : 228,
"LOT" : "0136A",
"FIPS_ST" : 47,
"FIPS_CTY" : 179,
"LATITUDE" : 36.292787,
"LONGITUDE" : -82.568171,
"ADDR_TYP" : 1,
"MSA" : 3660,
"CBSA" : 27740,
"ADDR_LINE" : 3,
"DMA_SUPPR" : "",
"GEO_MATCH" : 1,
"CENS_TRACT" : 61900,
"CENS_BLK_GRP" : 1,
"CENS_BLK" : 17,
"CENS_MED_HOME_VALUE" : 953,
"CENS_MED_HH_INCOME" : 304,
"CRA" : "",
"Z4_TYP" : "S",
"DSF_IND" : 1,
"DPD_IND" : "N",
"PHONE_FLAG" : "Y",
"PHONE" : NumberLong("4237730233"),
"TIME_ZN" : "E",
"GENDER" : "M",
"NEW_TO_BLD" : "",
"SOURCES" : 19,
"BASE_VER_DT" : 20101,
"COMP_ID" : NumberLong("3769001836"),
"IND_ID" : 1,
"INF_HH_RANK" : 1,
"HOME_OWNR_SRC" : "V",
"DOB_YR" : 1975,
"DOB_MON" : 7,
"DOB_DAY" : 10,
"EXACT_AGE" : 39,
"AGE" : 39,
"HH_INCOME" : "D",
"NET_WORTH" : "G",
"CREDIT_LINES" : "",
"CREDIT_RANGE_NEW" : "",
"EDUC" : "A",
"OCC_OCCUP" : "E",
"OCC_OCCUP_DET" : "",
"OCC_BUSN_OWNR" : "",
"NUM_KIDS" : 3,
"PRES_KIDS" : "Y",
"KIDS_M_0_2" : "",
"KIDS_F_0_2" : "",
"KIDS_U_0_2" : "Y",
"KIDS_M_3_5" : "",
"KIDS_F_3_5" : "",
"KIDS_U_3_5" : "Y",
"KIDS_M_6_10" : "",
"KIDS_F_6_10" : "",
"KIDS_U_6_10" : "",
"KIDS_M_11_15" : "",
"KIDS_F_11_15" : "",
"KIDS_U_11_15" : "",
"KIDS_M_16_17" : "",
"KIDS_F_16_17" : "",
"KIDS_U_16_17" : "Y",
"HH_MARITAL_STAT" : "S",
"HOME_OWNR" : "O",
"LOR" : 7,
"DWELL_TYP" : "S",
"NUM_ADULTS" : 1,
"HH_SIZE" : 2,
"HOME_MKT_VALUE" : "F",
"GENS" : 2,
"ADULTS_M_18_24" : "",
"ADULTS_F_18_24" : "",
"ADULTS_U_18_24" : "",
"ADULTS_M_25_34" : "",
"ADULTS_F_25_34" : "",
"ADULTS_U_25_34" : "",
"ADULTS_M_35_44" : "Y",
"ADULTS_F_35_44" : "",
"ADULTS_U_35_44" : "",
"ADULTS_M_45_54" : "",
"ADULTS_F_45_54" : "",
"ADULTS_U_45_54" : "",
"ADULTS_M_55_64" : "",
"ADULTS_F_55_64" : "",
"ADULTS_U_55_64" : "",
"ADULTS_M_65_74" : "",
"ADULTS_F_65_74" : "",
"ADULTS_U_65_74" : "",
"ADULTS_M_75PLUS" : "",
"ADULTS_F_75PLUS" : "",
"ADULTS_U_75PLUS" : ""
}
```

I have around 200000000 documents in the collection.

Following is my angular controller

```
$http.post('/api/allsearch',
        {
            "everything":$scope.filterSearch ,
            "searchid":$routeParams.id, 
            "filterId": $scope.filterId, 
            "zipgroup" : $scope.zipgroup
        },{timeout:600000})
        .success(function(data){

            for(var i=0; i<data.zips.length;i++){
                oneset={
                    "zip": data.zips[i],
                    "state": data.states[i],
                    "city": data.cities[i],
                    "distance": data.distances[i],
                    "count": data.counted_results[i]
                };
                $scope.totalCount+=data.counted_results[i];
                $scope.results.push(oneset);
            }
            angular.forEach($scope.results, function (result) {
                    result.distance = parseFloat(result.distance);
                });
            $rootScope.processing=false;
            $scope.filterlinkdisplay=true;
    });
```

And these are my node api functions related to the request.

```
    api.route('/allsearch')
    .post(function(req,res){
        var filters=req.body.everything;
        var filterid=req.body.filterId;
        var searchid=req.body.searchid;
        var zipgroup=req.body.zipgroup;
        var myObject = new Array();


        Searchradius.findOne({"searchid" : searchid, user: req.decoded.id}).exec(function(err, docs) {

            var asyncTasks = [];

            // Loop through some items
            zipgroup.forEach(function(item){
              // We don't actually execute the async action here
              // We add a function containing it to an array of "tasks"
              asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
                // Call an async function, often a save() to DB
                searchingalgo(item, filters, filterid,  function(pers){
                        myObject[item] = pers;
                      // Async call is done, alert via callback
                  callback();
                });
              });
            });


            Async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(){
                //console.log(myObject);
                Searchradius.update({ _id: searchid }, { $set: { ucounteds: myObject , uzips: zipgroup }}, function(err, result){
                    if(err) {
                        res.send(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    var fields = ['city', 'state', 'zip','distance', 'count'];
                    var myresults = [];
                    var tc=0;
                    var newMyobj= new Array();
                    co=0;
                    zipgroup.forEach(function(item){
                        tc+=myObject[item];
                        //myresults.push(jobj);
                    });

                    for(i=0;i<zipgroup.length;i++){
                        newMyobj[i]=myObject[zipgroup[i]];
                    }
                    console.log(tc);
                    Searchfilter.update({ _id: filterid }, { $set: { counted_results: tc }}, function(err, resultupdate){
                    });


                    res.json({ 
                    success: true,
                    zips: zipgroup,
                    states: docs.states,
                    cities: docs.cities,
                    distances: docs.distances,
                    counted_results : newMyobj,
                    });

                });     //update searchradius
            });         //getdata function 
        });             //searchradius findone
    });


function searchingalgo(zip, filerobject, filterid, callback){

 var query = Consumer1s.count({ "ZIP": zip});
 if(filerobject.ac){
        var ac = Object.keys(filerobject.ac);
        var adultagecriteria= [];
        ac.forEach(function(entry) {
            var prop={};
            prop[entry]="Y";
            adultagecriteria.push(prop);
        });
        query.or(adultagecriteria);
 }

 if(filerobject.child){
        var child = Object.keys(filerobject.child);
        var children= [];
        child.forEach(function(entry) {
            var prop={};
            prop[entry]="Y";
            children.push(prop);
        });
        query.or(children);
  }

  if(filerobject.HH_INCOME){
    query.where('HH_INCOME', filerobject.HH_INCOME);
  }

  if(filerobject.NET_WORTH){
    query.where('NET_WORTH', filerobject.NET_WORTH);
  }

  if(filerobject.GENDER){
   query.where('GENDER', filerobject.GENDER);
  }

  query.exec(function(err,dc){
    if(filterid){ 
    Searchfilter.update({ _id: filterid }, { $set: { filters: filerobject }}, function(err, result){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }       
        //  console.log(result);
                //result= dc;
                callback(dc);
            });
   }else{
        callback(dc);
    }
  });
 }
```

zipgroup is of the type

```
[37663, 37664, 37669, 37671, 37660, 37669, 37667, 37668, 37666, 37665, 37662, 37661 ]
```

Basically the concept is counting the number of records based on the ZIP or ADULTS_*info and basically all the fields in the document.

I have done the indexing on ZIP. It helps speeding when there are no filters but if the filters(usually like) include

```
{ 
GENDER: '',
HH_INCOME: 'A',
OCC_OCCUP: 'B',
ac: 
{ ADULTS_F_18_24: true,
  ADULTS_F_24_35: true,
  ADULTS_M_18_24: true,
  ADULTS_M_24_35: true },
child: { KIDS_F_0_2: true, KIDS_F_6_10: true }
 }
```

The query becomes too slow and the node app crashes. 
1. I need ways to increase the query time of mongodb (apart from indexing). 
2. I need node app to start again automatically when it has crashed. 
3. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Also I tried increasing the old_max_space_size to 2000000 but that does not work..

Comment: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting.

Comment: Maybe a very crude idea, but isn't increasing memory on the server a solution? The process can become slow because it needs to use virtual memory.

Comment: This might help you. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8019 and http://www.webpagetest.org/forums/showthread.php?tid=13911 .Can't say exactly the reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

Comment: @GamerNebulae I am working this application on a Macintosh System. OSX Yosemite 10.10.2   Processor 3.2Ghz Intel Core i5. Memory is 8GB 1600MHz DDR3.   Any suggestions how I can allocate more virtual memory to the mongodb and node process

Comment: @MHakvoort  I tried doing this.. No Change in the problem

Comment: @SatyamSaxena Node.js / V8 is not good working with very large amounts of memory because of GC, so adding memory is usually not a good idea.  If you need to count large volumes of data, do it in MongoDB with aggregation framework (that's what MongoDB is for), not in your Node.js app.

Comment: @kyrylkov Can u suggest aggregation query for the above metioned..

Comment: @SatyamSaxena you should post it as a separate question for MongoDB gurus, preferably with verbal description of the query as the code above is not easy to read